# FastAPI database dependency setup for connection pooling

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Consider the following fastapi setup:

```
application.add_event_handler(
    "startup",
    create_start_app_handler(application, settings),
)

def create_start_app_handler(
    app: FastAPI,
    settings: AppSettings,
) -> Callable: 
    async def start_app() -> None:
        await connect_to_db(app, settings)
    return start_app

async def connect_to_db(app: FastAPI, settings: AppSettings) -> None:
    db_url = settings.DATABASE_URL
    engine = create_engine(db_url, pool_size=settings.POOL_SIZE, max_overflow=settings.MAX_OVERFLOW)

    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()

    def close_db():
        db.close()
        engine.dispose()

    app.state.db = db
    app.state.close_db = close_db
```

close_db is used to close the database connection on app shutdown
I have the following dependencies defined:

```
def _get_db(request: Request) -> Generator:
    yield request.app.state.db

def get_repository(
    repo_type: Type[BaseRepository],
) -> Callable[[Session], BaseRepository]:
    def _get_repo(
        sess: Session = Depends(_get_db),
    ) -> BaseRepository:
        return repo_type(sess)

    return _get_repo
```

Would this still allow me to take advantage of connection pooling?

Also, this feels a little hacky and I could use some feedback if there's anything in particular that I should not be doing.

Answer (score 0):

To be blunt; it seems overly complicated for something that is pretty well documented in the [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-a-dependency).

In your case, you create only 1 instance of `SessionLocal()` and will share that across all your requests (because you store it in the `app.state`). In other words: no this will not be using connection pooling, it will use only 1 connection.

A better approach is to yield an instance per request, either via middleware or via a dependency. That way, the connection is actually closed when the incoming request has been fully handled. For example, like this:

```py
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/")
def root(db: SessionLocal = Depends(get_db)):
    return "hello world"
```

I am not sure how you ended up where you ended up, but I would recommend to refactor a bunch.

Comment: 200 concurrent request will open 200 concurrent connections with database. Won't be a great idea, need to pre-create some connections and re-use them.

Comment: This is illustrating the basic concept indeed, it is easily adaptable to include connectionpooling

Comment: As per my understanding, create engine w.r.t SQLALCHEMY will create a default connection pool of size 5 with QueuePool as it's default implementation. And each SESSIONLOCAL instance will utilise the connection from same pool. It will not create extra connections outside the pool even if the concurrent requests are 200 or 2000. And agreed docs are well documented w.r.t FASTAPI.

Comment: @ArpanSharma how it will work with multiple applications running under ALB?
let sat there are 10 applications running using docker and each creates 5 pools using sqlalcmy so there will be total 50 connections.
how do we limit the connections in that situation?

Comment: You have to consider the MAX DB Connections available to connect.  If you are in micoservice world where you have DB per microservice, 50 connections are okay to have. I have seen DB configs which allow 300-400 connections at any given point of time.